# Как в Arch Linux Установить пакет с флагом y?

Tags: archlinux

Есть ли аналог для Arch Linux линуксовой команды apt install <имя пакета> y ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Флаг `--noconfirm` будет отвечать на все вопросы ответом по умолчанию.

Если вам нужно отвечать на все вопросы `yes`, то подойдёт такой вариант:

`yes | sudo pacman -S firefox`